# How to make rain that's hardware friendly?

Tags: particles, settings

I'm not aiming for a photorealistic scene. Just a simple rain using mesh/sprite/decal. Like in Max Payne. I can't seem to find the right guide. Honestly most of the guides i've found aims on photorealism.

I've tried the particle emitter, and i wanted the snow to be going sideway, to fake windy environment, but it just ended up like looking like ants throwing snowball at me. Anyway i could change it so that it always move in 1 direction?

Also, I've tried using mesh, it turns out great, but the problem is, when i moved the camera sideways, well, I pretty much can't see it, because its a singular plane. I've even tried the randomize setting, and it was okay, wish it could've been better. How would you guys do this? Is using particle emitter the only option? Any suggestion would help.

[image]I'm looking to make a rain like this. Just a simple one thats hardware friendly.

[image]or snow like this

[image]I've tried the velocity setting, but it ends up looking like some tiny creature throwing snowball lol

[image]trying with the particle mesh, it was okay, but..

[image]i cant see anything sideways lol

[image]randomize rotation is okay, but i wish it would've been better

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather that point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particle mesh is the best solution for you.

Use a simple plane with a transparent texture for a raindrop for example.

You can either have 1 plane which is used as the main object for your particle system, and add a look at constraint, so it always rotates towards your camera.

But you can also have 2 planes merged into 1, where the first plane is just like I said above, and the second plane is rotated 90 degrees in the Z axis. That way, when you move your camera, the raindrop will still be visible.

Comment: okay that could work, any idea on how to make it go sideways? like its been blowing by wind?

Comment: Yes! You can tilt the emmiter mesh to any angle you want, and in your particle menu, under velocity, increase your Normal. That way, your particles will shoot out of your emmiter. You can always rotate your main raindrop mesh to modify their angle. To finish, you can add some randomized rotation in the particle parameters. Good luck!